# How to find a particular contact in contacts manager?

Tags: android, contacts

Given a particular  contact in an  Android device,  is it possible for my app to find this contact  in the contact manager  after a few weeks/months?

I am thinking something  along the lines of:

```
select  contact where ID = <some persistent id >
```

Only from what I understand, from the documentation,  a contact id can change if the device is synced with the cloud.

How is it possible then to work with a specific contact over time?